# Plumbing command to get the result of git-bisect with --no-checkout

Tags: git, git-bisect, git-plumbing

I'm writing a script which automatically finds a specific commit.

I've reached the part when I'm calling `git bisect start --no-checkout` and `git bisect run ./my_check_commit_script.sh`. It finds and displays the correct commit. However, I don't know how can I get the hash of this commit in my script.

The reference `BISECT_HEAD` seems to still point at the previous `old` revision.
Other than that, using `git show-ref`, I've found a ref `refs/bisect/new` which seems to point to the correct commit but I don't know if I can rely on it existing. There is a bunch of `refs/bisect/old*` and I suspect it may be an accident that there is only a single `refs/bisect/new`.

How can I get the hash of the commit found by `git bisect` in my script?

---

Here is a script that crates a repository and successfully calls `git bisect run` on it:

```bash
git init repo
cd repo

echo a >foo
git add foo
git commit -m "Initial commit"

echo b >foo
git commit -a -m "Some commit"

echo c >foo
git commit -a -m "First commit which matches criteria"

echo d >foo
git commit -a -m "Some commit"

echo e >foo
git commit -a -m "Last commit"

git bisect start --no-checkout
git bisect old HEAD~4
git bisect new HEAD
git bisect run git merge-base --is-ancestor BISECT_HEAD HEAD~3
```

Comment: The rev under test is `HEAD` (always). If the test succeeds, use `git rev-parse HEAD` and you have the hash ID.

Comment: @torek No. It would work if I wasn't using `--no-checkout` but with this flag Git doesn't checkout the rev under test so `HEAD` stays where it was before `git bisect`.

Comment: When `git bisect start --no-checkout` doesn't check out a rev under test, the rev in the working tree (which is the one under test) is `HEAD`. Are you talking about using `git bisect` in a bare repository? (Here the idea is different, as you're not actually testing any checked-out version, but here `BISECT_HEAD` *should* work. If it doesn't, that would seem to be a bug, either in the docs or the implementation or both. I've never actually used this mode myself.)

Comment: @torek I'm not doing it in a bare repository but it is the same situation. In a bare repository `--no-checkout` is implied.

Comment: In that case, what does your `run` script look like? It should explicitly use `BISECT_HEAD` for everything and not examine the working tree at all.

Comment: @torek Yes, it uses `BISECT_HEAD` for everything. I'm doing it so I'm able to run the script without disturbing the current working copy. Wait a moment. I'm preparing a complete example.

Comment: Note that you can use `git worktree add` to create a new worktree for bisection, without disturbing the current working tree. If there is some issue with BISECT_HEAD here that would provide a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference `refs/bisect/new` that you've found is the correct one to use. The command `rev-parse bisect/new` guarantees to always return the hash of the first "new" commit.

The Git manual tells that in the section ["Basic bisect commands: start, bad, good"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_basic_bisect_commands_start_bad_good) (emphasis mine):

> Eventually there will be no more revisions left to inspect, and the command will print out a description of the first bad commit. **The reference refs/bisect/bad will be left pointing at that commit.**

The manual calls it `refs/bisect/bad` but because you're using `old` & `new` instead of `good` & `bad`, the reference name also changes.
(Using options `--term-good` and `--term-bad` you can change this name to anything you want.)